# Problems with copying a column as an additional column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
def prep_data(embeddings, df):
    """
    Prepares training and test set the train and test data used.

    :return: train and test set
    """
    #Original_DF
    OD_df = df.reset_index()
    OD_df.loc[:,'type'] = 'nails'
    
    embeddings_df = pd.DataFrame(data=embeddings)
    embeddings_df = embeddings_df.reset_index()
    
    embedded_df = pd.merge(embeddings_df, OD_df, on='index')
    
    train, valid = train_test_split(embedded_df, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, shuffle=True)
    #train_col = ['train'] * len(train) 
    #train['split']= train_col 

    train.loc[:,'split'] = 'train'
    
    #valid_col = ['valid'] * len(valid) 
    #valid['split']= valid_col 
    valid.loc[:,'split'] = 'valid'
    
    x_train, y_train = train.iloc[:, :3840], train.loc[:,'nails']
    x_valid, y_valid = valid.iloc[:, :3840], valid.loc[:,'nails']


    return x_train, y_train, x_valid, y_valid
```

#### Calling Code

```
x_train, y_train, x_valid, y_valid = prep_data(embeddings, df)
```

I get the following warning. I've tried implemented the `.iloc` method and `.loc` as well, even just normal subsetting without the previous but it continues to give me the error message. When I revise the dataframes, everything seems to be in order, but I'm not sure on how to suppress or overcome this warning.

### warning

```
/home/maria/my_python_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1596: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
```

Comment: Did you try: `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None` to suppress warning? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20627316/5916727

Comment: This is a warning message. Not an error.

Comment: Generally more reasonable to understand the cause and address the warning than to simply suppress it.  The warning is there for a reason.  Yes, it’s a book in itself, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954986/6340496) explains it nicely.